# PHP checkdate() with multiple conditions

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I am trying to use `checkdate()` in an `IF` statement with other conditions:

```
if ( $segment[1] == 'living-life-lab' && 
     $segment[2] == 'activities' && 
     $segment[3] == 'letter-scramble-game' && 
    ( checkdate( $segment[5] , $segment[6] , $segment[4] ) === true ) ) 
{
```

But `checkdate()` returns a warning instead of just moving to the next `IF` when the value of $segment[4] is "printables" , $segment[5] is "rss" and $segment[6] is "feed".

> Warning: checkdate() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in /home/vhosts/rons-home.net/LivingLifeLab/url/url.php on line 709

What change do I need to make to the `IF` statement to allow a date but move to the next `IF` when $segment[4] , $segment[5] & $segment[6] do not form a date?

Comment: Well as those values dont look anything like a date or the Day,Month,Year parts of a date, you had better validate first that you are looking at the right data i.e. a date before using it in a `checkdate()`

Comment: Could you please show what data is in `$segment` array?. Just the result of `print_r ($segment)`. Thanks.

Comment: Why not write such code? You could simply check whether the three arguments are integers or not

Comment: I did what @RiggsFolly suggested